# embed MVC script block in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to mix MVC2 <%:  %> script block in jQuery script. It takes the user entry, changes the form action attribute with the Url.RouteUrl(), and post the form when the text box loses focus.  Here is a section of a appScript.js file

```
$("input#txtSSN").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != undefined && jQuery.trim($(this).val()).length != 0) {
        alert('txtSSN.blur() = ' + $(this).val());
        var formAction = '<%:Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "controller1", action = "SSN", ID = escape(jQuery.trim($(this).val())) }) %>';
        $(this).parents('form:first').form.attr('action', formAction);
        $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    } //if
}); //blur
```

This .js is referenced the Site.master "script src=" block. Everything works except it doesn't post the form with the updated href.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The MVC2 code runs on your server before the page is delivered to the client browser.  Once it's in the browser, how exactly would you expect it to run that script block code? It's in a computer far, far away from your server.

Comment: Shouldn't the server evaluate that part of the server script where Url.RouteUrl() is used, then flushes the html string down to the client browser?  I thought it would generate "/controller1/SSN/1234".  I think it is becuase I am using this in the .js file, not in the aspx file's <script> block.

Comment: that's correct. Don't make a formAction in javascript. Have a formAction in the HTML and submit the form with javascript if you must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the server code blocks only in the aspx files, not in external .js files

Comment: How can I do it in .js file to achieve the same Url.RouteUrl() result?