# App Root in Javascript

Tags: jquery, root

I put as much as my javascript in the MyApp.js so that I don't have to hunt for  tag among ASPX pages.  However, I have problem with my app root when the development directory and the deployment directory are different, so I use a global variable (appRoot) to manually change the path between deployment and development time.  I tried window.location.url, window.location.host, etc, nothing worked.  Since I can not use <%: Url.Content("~/AppRoot") %> in .js, how can I make any path that is referenced in the .js independent on where my deployment directory is? Thank you for your help.

```
var appRoot =  "/2_1/"; //deployment path  
//var appRoot = "/"; //development path

$(function () {
    $("#txtSSNPage1,#txtSSNPage2").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != undefined && jQuery.trim($(this).val()).length != 0) {
        try {
            var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
            form.attr('action', appRoot + 'Controller1/SSN/' + escape(jQuery.trim($(this).val())));
            form.submit();
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.description);
        }
    } //if
}); //blur

$("input#txtNamePage3").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != undefined && jQuery.trim($(this).val()).length != 0) {
        try {
            var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
            form.attr('action', appRoot + 'Controller2/SSN/' + escape(jQuery.trim($(this).val())));
            form.submit();
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err.description);
        }
    } //if
}); //blur

$("input#txtNamePage4").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != undefined && jQuery.trim($(this).val()).length != 0) {
        try {
            var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
            form.attr('action', appRoot + 'Controller2/FullName/' + escape(jQuery.trim($(this).val())));
            form.submit();
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err.description);
        }
    } //if
}); //blur
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
<% response.write "<script>var appRoot =  """ & Url.Content("~/AppRoot") & """</script>" %>
```

before calling the .js file in the dinamic part of your app (.aspx)

Comment: is it posible that you also have a flag for dinamic parts to distinghish between development and deployment, so you can use that flag with an if with diferent literals on then and else sides.  Advice: I do not know asp.net, so be sure that Url.Content("~/AppRoot") can't be inyected or sanitize it

Comment: Thanks. I modified your suggestion as below and put it in the Site.Master and it worked.

    <script type="text/javascript">var appRoot =  '<%:Url.Content("~/")%>'</script>
 <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyApp.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: you can use this way to solve your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6419950/443685) too.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a script that's always included on every page you can use its location to identify the site root:

```
var myScript = $('script[src$="myscript.js"]');
var baseUrl = myScript.attr('src').substring(0, myScript.attr('src').length - "myscript.js".length);
```

Adjust the second line as needed if you store the script in a Scripts subdirectory or similar.